# How to speed up Element.fade function

Tags: mootools

I'd like to speed up the `fade()` function, but the arguments the function accepts are about opacity, not speed. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a new tween duration like:

```js
$('slow').set('tween', {duration: 5000});
$('fast').set('tween', {duration: 100});
$$('div').fade();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>


<div id="slow">I'm going to fade slowly!</div>
<div id="normal">I'm going to fade normal speed!</div>
<div id="fast">I'm going to fade fast!</div>
```

**jsFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/8vjsfpfq/](http://jsfiddle.net/8vjsfpfq/__)**